# byte order using GCC struct bit packing

Tags: c, endianness, can-bus

I am using GCC struct bit fields in an attempt interpret 8 byte CAN message data.  I wrote a small program as an example of one possible message layout.  The code and the comments should describe my problem.  I assigned the 8 bytes so that all 5 signals should equal 1.  As the output shows on an Intel PC, that is hardly the case.  All CAN data that I deal with is big endian, and the fact that they are almost never packed 8 bit aligned makes htonl() and friends useless in this case.  Does anyone know of a solution?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

typedef union
{
    unsigned char data[8];
    struct { 
        unsigned int signal1 : 32;
        unsigned int signal2 :  6;
        unsigned int signal3 : 16;
        unsigned int signal4 :  8;
        unsigned int signal5 :  2;
    } __attribute__((__packed__));
} _message1;

int main()
{
    _message1 message1;
    unsigned char incoming_data[8]; //This is how this message would come in from a CAN bus for all signals == 1

    incoming_data[0] = 0x00;
    incoming_data[1] = 0x00;
    incoming_data[2] = 0x00;
    incoming_data[3] = 0x01; //bit 1 of signal 1
    incoming_data[4] = 0x04; //bit 1 of signal 2
    incoming_data[5] = 0x00;
    incoming_data[6] = 0x04; //bit 1 of signal 3
    incoming_data[7] = 0x05; //bit 1 of signal 4 and signal 5

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
        message1.data[i] = incoming_data[i];
    }

    printf("signal1 = %x\n", message1.signal1);
    printf("signal2 = %x\n", message1.signal2);
    printf("signal3 = %x\n", message1.signal3);
    printf("signal4 = %x\n", message1.signal4);
    printf("signal5 = %x\n", message1.signal5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because struct packing order varies between compilers and architectures, the best option is to use a helper function to pack/unpack the binary data instead.

For example:

```
static inline void message1_unpack(uint32_t            *fields,
                                   const unsigned char *buffer)
{
    const uint64_t  data = (((uint64_t)buffer[0]) << 56)
                         | (((uint64_t)buffer[1]) << 48)
                         | (((uint64_t)buffer[2]) << 40)
                         | (((uint64_t)buffer[3]) << 32)
                         | (((uint64_t)buffer[4]) << 24)
                         | (((uint64_t)buffer[5]) << 16)
                         | (((uint64_t)buffer[6]) <<  8)
                         |  ((uint64_t)buffer[7]);
    fields[0] =  data >> 32;           /* Bits 32..63 */
    fields[1] = (data >> 26) & 0x3F;   /* Bits 26..31 */
    fields[2] = (data >> 10) & 0xFFFF; /* Bits 10..25 */
    fields[3] = (data >> 2)  & 0xFF;   /* Bits  2..9  */
    fields[4] =  data        & 0x03;   /* Bits  0..1  */
}
```

Note that because the consecutive bytes are interpreted as a single unsigned integer (in big-endian byte order), the above will be perfectly portable.

Instead of an array of fields, you could use a structure, of course; but it does not need to have any resemblance to the on-the-wire structure at all.  However, if you have several different structures to unpack, an array of (maximum-width) fields usually turns out to be easier and more robust.

All sane compilers will optimize the above code just fine. In particular, GCC with `-O2` does a very good job.

The inverse, packing those same fields to a buffer, is very similar:

```
static inline void  message1_pack(unsigned char  *buffer,
                                  const uint32_t *fields)
{
    const uint64_t  data = (((uint64_t)(fields[0]          )) << 32)
                         | (((uint64_t)(fields[1] & 0x3F   )) << 26)
                         | (((uint64_t)(fields[2] & 0xFFFF )) << 10)
                         | (((uint64_t)(fields[3] & 0xFF   )) <<  2)
                         | ( (uint64_t)(fields[4] & 0x03   )       );
    buffer[0] = data >> 56;
    buffer[1] = data >> 48;
    buffer[2] = data >> 40;
    buffer[3] = data >> 32;
    buffer[4] = data >> 24;
    buffer[5] = data >> 16;
    buffer[6] = data >>  8;
    buffer[7] = data;
}
```

Note that the masks define the field length (`0x03` = 0b11 (2 bits), `0x3F` = 0b111111 (16 bits), `0xFF` = 0b11111111 (8 bits), `0xFFFF` = 0b1111111111111111 (16 bits)); and the shift amount depends on the bit position of the least significant bit in each field.

To verify such functions work, pack, unpack, repack, and re-unpack a buffer that should contain all zeros except one of the fields all ones, and verify the data stays correct over two roundtrips. It usually suffices to detect the typical bugs (wrong bit shift amounts, typos in masks).

Note that documentation will be key to ensure the code remains maintainable. I'd personally add comment blocks before each of the above functions, similar to

```
/* message1_unpack(): Unpack 8-byte message to 5 fields:
       field[0]: Foobar. Bits 32..63.
       field[1]: Buzz.   Bits 26..31.
       field[2]: Wahwah. Bits 10..25.
       field[3]: Cheez.  Bits  2..9.
       field[4]: Blop.   Bits  0..1.
*/
```

with the field "names" reflecting their names in documentation.

Comment: Yeah this is the direction I was heading in.  I was hoping that I could use the GCC bitfields to simplify this some, since I will be dealing with hundreds, even thousands of CAN messages.

Comment: @Doug: You could treat each message as a bit stream, and use a function to extract the next N bits from it, with not much more overhead. Want an example of that approach?